# Slope field of a Differential equation does not math slope of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a ode $y'(x) = g(x,y)$. See below the slope field:

[image]

Ive been trying to find solutions that have linear form. That is, find all $y(x)$ such that $y''=0$. For my example, I found $y = x-2$ to be the solution. But, as you can see below, the the slope elements at points in $y=x-2$ are $-1$ and not $1$! . Does this mean that I can discard this solution? Why is this happening?

Comment: Nope, and just solve the equations $y'' = 0 $  and obtain three lines $y= mx+b$ one of them being $y= x-2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=x-2$ is the pink line in your picture, it is not a solution of the differential equation.  It looks like there are two solutions of the form $y = x + c$ though, maybe approximately $c = -1.5$ and $c = -3.5$.

Comment: but it is strange because when solving $y'' = 0$ I obtain three lines one being $y = x-2$.

Comment: I think what you're finding with $y = x-2$ are inflection points, where the solution curve switches from being concave to convex ("concave down" to "concave up" in the terminology of a typical calculus course).

Comment: Say we have a de $y' = g(x,y)$. If we want to find solutions that have the form $y=mx+b$, don't we need to solve the equaition $y'' = 0 $?

Comment: No, we need to substitute $mx+b$ for $y$, and see for what values of $m$ and $b$ we have an identity $m = g(x, mx+b)$ (true for all $x$).

Comment: I see! thanks! Now, is it true that any stationary point in a solution curve intersect those $y=mx+b$? It is not clear from the field, but I can also solve $g(x,y)=0$ to find the stationary points, correct?

Comment: For instance, when I solve $g(x,y) = 0$ I obtain $y = x-1$